# About Dharma Sastha in Vedas

Tags: vedas, identification-request, ayyappa

Some times ago, i have learned about a info that there a reference about Sastha from Taittriya Aranyaka:

> Anthah Pravishtas Sastha Jananaam Sarvaathma | Sarvaa: Praja Yathraikam Bavanthi |
>
> Meaning: "Where all are united, He who has entered within, that are born, and is the self of all, is beyond comprehension, He is Sastha the ruler of all things”

I'm about to asked it many days. So my question is:-

- Does Dharma Sastha mentioned in Vedas, other than Tattriya Aranyaka?
- Also, which chapter of Taittriya Aranyaka mentioned the above reference about him?