# Is Dharmasastha mentioned in Tantras and Agamas?

Tags: scripture, tantra, ayyappa

Is Dharma Sastha mentioned in Tantras and Agamas, like Puranas and Vedas (as i discussed about it [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57532/about-dharma-sastha-in-vedas))? If yes, which Tantra mentioned him or at least they mentioned "Sastha" (but that is not him)?

Answer (score 1):

*Ākāśabhairavakalpa* (an independent text whose colophons state it to be a part of a *Mahāśaivatantra*) does mention *Śāstā* as an *āvaraṇa-devatā* of *Śarabha*. Chapter 51 of this text expounding the *mantra*, *yantra* & *avāraṇa-devatā*s of *Śāstā*.

Rites of *Śāstā* worship are also well documented in the *Tantrapaddhati* composed around late 12th - early 13th century by the *Śaivasiddhānta* scholar *Īśānaśiva* (popularly known as *Īśānaśivagurudevapaddhati*). *Īśānaśiva*'s *guru* *Vimalaśiva* was the *rājaguru* of *Jayasiṃha Kalacuri*, king of *Tripurī* (1163-1188).

Another well-known *Tāntrika* manual named *Tantrasamuccaya* composed by a Keralite *brāhmaṇa* named *Nārāyaṇa* composed in 1428 also discusses about *Śāstā* worship.

The *Pāñcarātra* text *Pādma saṃhitā* also has some passing references to *Śastā*.

Answer (score 1):

There are mentions of Śāstā in *Suprabhedāgama*, *Kāraṇāgama*, and *Aṁśumadbhedāgama*. 
 The following extract is taken from [*Elements of Hindu Iconography* (Vol. 2, Part 2, pg. 485-490)](https://archive.org/details/xHNQ_elements-of-hindu-iconography-vol-2-part-2-t.-a.-gopinatha-rao/page/n163/mode/2up?view=theater)

Śāstā is known by the names Ārya or Hariharaputra. The *Suprabhedāgama* very distinctly mentions that Śāstā was born of Mohinī's saṁyoga with Hara, in line with the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa(3.10.75). *Padmasaṁhitā* states that pūjā in the mandira of Ārya should be performed by a Pāraśava (i.e. Niṣāda). The descriptions of the pratimās of Śāstā or Ārya are found in *Aṁśumadbhedāgama*, *Suprabhedāgama* and *Kāraṇāgama*.

The figure of Śāstā should have four arms and three eyes, and a peaceful countenance ; its colour should be golden yellow and it should be draped in silk garments. It must be seated upon a padmāsana. The front right and left hands should be held in the abhaya and varada mudrās respectively and the back right and left hands should bear a khaḍga and a kheṭaka respectively. This is the description given in *Aṁśumadbhedāgama*.

*Suprabhedāgama* has a very different description altogether ; it states that the figure of Śāstā shuold have only two arms and two eyes and a dark complexion. It should be adorned with all ornaments and a white yajñopavīta. The arms and lefs should be kept folded : in the right hand there should be a crooked stick (called śeṇḍu in Tamil) and in the left fruits and tender leaves of plants (pallava). The body of this devatā should be like a bhūta, with a big belly. The hair on his head should be jet black in colour. Śāstā should be represented as playing with dogs, sheep and fowls. He has two wives named Madanā and Varṇanī ; the figures of these should be sculpted one on either side of that of Śāstā, with large breasts and adorned with all ornaments. To the left of Śāstā, there should be the figure of Damanaka.

*Kāraṇāgama* agrees with *Aṁśumadbhedāgama* in taking Śāstā as the son of Mohinī & Hara, but states, with *Suprabhedāgama*, that Śāstā should have only two arms and two eyes, and a dark complexion. Śāstā should be seated on a pīṭha, with his left leg hanging down the seat and the right one folded and rested upon the seat vertically. On the knee of this latter leg should rest the elbow of the stretched arm. In the right hand, there should be a vajradaṇḍa. The figure of Śāstā should be of youthful and peaceful appearance. The hair of his head should be like blue-black ink and be spread out. His vāhana is the elephant as also is the crest on his dhvaja. He should have by his side a blitheful damsel. At the end of the description, it is mentioned that the colour of Śāstā might be blue, white or dark, his vāhana the bull, that he might have four arms and that the crest on his dhvaja a cock. Furthermore, *Kāraṇāgama* states that if Ārya is to be represented as a yogin, he should be sculptured as seated in yogāsana ; if as a vidyārthī of Veda, he should wear a pavitra (a ring made of kuśa grass) on his fingers, and wear his upper cloth on his shoulder in the upavīta fashion and be seated in vīrāsana. If Śāstā is to be shown as seated in the sukhāsana fashion, the right foot of the bent right leg resting upon the thigh of the left leg should be hanging. The gaze of Sukhāsana Ārya should be fixed on his right foot.

Comment: Is Madana & Varnini actually Poorna-Pushkala?

Comment: that's right, Aiyaṉār (ஐயனார்) is Śāstā.  @Boovanaes

Comment: In the Tamil country, Śāstā is known by the name Hariharaputra or more frequently Aiyaṉār (modification of Ārya). @Boovanaes

Comment: One small doubt: Who is Damanaka?

Comment: I also think that blitheful damsel is Prabhavati, the third consort of Sastha.

Comment: @Boovanaes TA Gopinath Rao states, "To the left of Śāsta, there should be the figure of Damanaka - who he is, is not mentioned - of ill looking features." https://archive.org/details/xHNQ_elements-of-hindu-iconography-vol-2-part-2-t.-a.-gopinatha-rao/page/n167/mode/2up?view=theater
In Skanda Purāṇa, there is a grass named Damanaka, which was earlier an asura killed by Viṣṇu. But I am not sure, if the Damanaka with Śāstā, is the same one, who was slain by Viṣṇu.

Comment: Hi Bingming, Can you write an answer to my other 2 questions about Dharma Sastha, here the links:-  [Q1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58334/is-dharma-sastha-mentioned-in-upapuranas) and [Q2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57532/about-dharma-sastha-in-vedas)

Comment: @Boovanaes If I do have an answer to those, I will write. I don't have any answers to those, as of now. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's Okay sir. If you find, i hope you'll write.

Comment: I don't know about Vettakkorumakan @Boovanaes